# How to get files inside multiple archives?

Tags: java

I have a file `a.zip` which contains `b.jar`, and `b.jar` contains `c.xml`.

How to create a URL for `b.jar` and `c.xml`?  I tried to create URL for `b.jar` as

```
jar:file:/dir/a.zip!/b.jar
```

Is this a valid URL?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html.I think you would be able to find a construction to get nested archives as well

Comment: Fixing the link for [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html)